# Strange Behaviour of "onclick" event of a button

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

html:

```
<div id="container">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="1024"></canvas>

 </div> 
<button id = "click" >fire</button>

 <script type="text/javascript" src = "Jquery/easy.js"></script>
```

javascript:

```
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
var chop1   = new Image();
chop1.src = "img/chopper.png";
var blt = new Image();
blt.src = "img/bullet.png"
var chopperX = 0;
var chopperY = 0;
var ascent = 2;
var limit = 500;
var start = null;
var bltX = 135;
var hit = document.getElementById("click");
window.onclick = function()
{
fly()
}
hit.onclick = function()
{
  fire();
}

function fire()
{
 bltX +=ascent;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(blt,bltX,30,
chop1.width, chop1.height);

requestAnimationFrame(fire);



}


function up()
{
    chopperY-=ascent;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(chop1,0,chopperY , 
              chop1.width, chop1.height);

    requestAnimationFrame(up);




if(chopperY == 0){

   fly();
  }
 }

function fly() {
chopperY+=ascent;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(chop1,0,chopperY , 
              chop1.width, chop1.height);
if (chopperY < limit) {
    requestAnimationFrame(fly);
}
if(chopperY==limit){

   up();
}
}
```

When i click on the fire button it doesn't call the "fire" method and calls the "fly" function. i want to know why "fly" method get called instead of "fire" method?
Is there any mistake in this code? what is the solution of it?

Comment: the fly() is called because you have `window.onclick` calling `fly()` and this will be triggered when you click any where on the screen ( even the button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two event handlers

```
window.onclick = function() {
    fly()
}
hit.onclick = function() {
  fire();
}
```

which by the way could be written

```
window.onclick = fly;
```

etc. But the click bubbles to the `window` level when you click any element inside the `window`, even `hit`, so the `fly()` function is called as well.

You could try stopping the propagation

```
hit.onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  fire();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There already is a solution for your problem:
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function)

What you want to do is:

```
document.getElementById("click").onclick = fire;
```