# Javascript run() Function is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but none of them seemed to solve my problem. I have this piece of code that won't run because it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: run is not defined`. I have tried to move the function into the body of the HTML, but to no avail. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <textarea name="Text1" cols="100"rows="20" id="textbox">
    </textarea>
    <button onclick="run()">Export to C++</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function run() {
            var code=new Array();
            var input = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            //convert things that are not subroutines here
            code.push(input);
            code.push("}");
        ...
        for (var i=0;i<code.length;i++)
            {
                document.write(code[i]+"<br>");
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

The `...` is irrelevant code.

Why isn't this working? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Check the console in your browser's developer tools. A syntax error in the <script> tag will cause the function to be undefined.

Comment: Using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after the page has been parsed is a bad idea ...

Comment: It isn't working because it's not defined before its used, move the script tag above the button.

Comment: @dsh Doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the script tag

Comment: @Ajaypayne Still doesn't work though, might have done it wrong.

Comment: I think @dsh means an error in the JavaScript. Can you post a [minimal working version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @APCoding are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @Ajaypayne This will run just fine in that position, something else must be the problem.

Comment: @APCoding Can you post the "irrelevant" code too?

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function

Comment: I think everything is irrelevant because even with tiniest code,I get the error too: http://jsfiddle.net/xeme2jLu/

Comment: @Abdul If you set up the fiddle properly, you don't get any error: http://jsfiddle.net/xeme2jLu/1/

Comment: @Mikey I see. I had it on `onLoad`

Comment: @APCoding Just a tip, don't use inline calls. It's bad practice and your HTML gets messy very quick. Better to use eventlisteners :)

Comment: Are you running this in your browser or in a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you remove the ellipsis (`...`) then your example works. Do you have that ellipsis in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it working fine for me, but as I can see the only reason for the problem is the following.

Your page is loading piece by piece from up to down, so all the scripts are going to be included and executed one by one, all the elements are going to be shown one by one as well.

That's not this case in fact, because you are using "on click" event and there are no init actions, so it should be working, but you can try to move your `<script></script>` at the top (before you assign event).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <textarea name="Text1" cols="100"rows="20" id="textbox">
    </textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         you script here
    </script>
    <button onclick="run()">Export to C++</button>

</html>
```

You may also replace the whole code inside of 
`<script></script>` 
by something like `alert("Hello");` to check if it's working. Possible you have the issue with internal code.

Comment: If I make the entire code just `alert("Hello");` it works. It must be an internal code problem