# How do you add controls on animation

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I was wondering how controls are added to an animation. I am currently building a js animation using Raphael javascript library. I know that you need to add a button to your html page.

```
<button id = "startButton" type="button">Start<Start></button>
```

But how would you link this to your animation to play/replay...

Comment: Just call some javascript with your animation in it, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function