# How to add javascript to button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, href

this might be very basic but I am still trying to figure it out because I cannot seem to get it correct.

The button

```
<a class="fusion-button button-flat button-square button-xlarge button-default button-40" target="_blank"><span class="fusion-button-text fusion-button-text-left">KÖP DITT CAMPINGKORT HÄR!</span></a>
```

And I need to add this

```
<a href="Javascript://Camping Key Europe" onclick="CampingKeyEurope(' blank', 'sv')">Köp Camping Key Europe</a>
```

Some things needs changing such in the next code but you get the idea, how can I make button work, so when they press it it open module? When I use the second code without button and only link, it works fine, module shows up.

Please help :)

Comment: The method you're using is severely outdated, look into external event handlers with `addEventListener`

Comment: If you want a button you should use the `<button>` element, not `<a>`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function for more information

Comment: I am using this code with Wordpress, this button is generated by the theme and I am trying to edit it.

Comment: In first case, your are using target="-blank" which means The target attribute specifies where to open the linked doc. Where as in the second case youn didn't use target attribute. I think you are trying to open the new page onclick. If yes, follow this: <a onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">
  Share Page
</a>

Comment: Also what is the code that `CampingKeyEurope` executes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<button type="button" class="fusion-button-text fusion-button-text-left" 
onclick="CampingKeyEurope(' blank', 'sv')">Button Text</button>
```

Building off the comment by Sterling Archer, you should attach event listeners outside of your HTML, so if you are using JQuery, in your $(document).ready() function you would add your onclick event there to your button like so:

```
$('.fusion-button-text.fusion-button-text-left').on('click', function() {});
```

Comment: I did this before you answered and it worked, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an event listener:

```
<a id="btn" class="fusion-button button-flat button-square button-xlarge button-default button-40" target="_blank">
  <span class="fusion-button-text fusion-button-text-left">KÖP DITT CAMPINGKORT HÄR!</span>
</a>

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () { 
  CampingKeyEurope(' blank', 'sv');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking through here, Its very useful: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Thatsnks for posting an answer its what makes this community work. Pages from W3schools can be an unreliable source and are generally frowned upon on SO. I recommend using the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) reference pages instead