# Trigger javascript with a id

Tags: javascript, html, function, triggers

I want to trigger a JavaScript function with a button that needs to do some things before it triggers the script (login).

At the moment the login happens before the href is triggered so thats great.
I was wondering if i could trigger a javascript function with the href.
So the href would have the functions ID in it?

How would I make that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an HTML button to call a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: onclick event would not work here, cause they are triggered before the login

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `onclick="functionname()"` in the `a` tag.

Comment: in the href tag? if i just add it in the anchor, it doesent work cause it runs the function before the login

Comment: Oh sorry. My mistake. I typed wrong. It has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove the `href` attribute as it is not an attribute supported by the [button tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp). Instead, add a click event listener to the button using JavaScript.

When the button is clicked the event handler should call a function that will do whatever pre-login stuff that needs to be done. You can then use a callback function to trigger the login. Using a callback guarantees all pre-login stuff will be done prior to login. Something like below:

```js
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  doPreLoginStuff(doLogin);
});

function doPreLoginStuff(callback) {
  console.log('Doing some stuff..');
  console.log('Doing some more stuff..');
  console.log('Doing even more stuff..');
  callback();
}

function doLogin() {
  console.log('All pre-login stuff done. Now we can trigger the login script');
  //now do login
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" data-ga="Era_Eurosport anon-client Player-Hero-Tellin CTA" class="btn btn--order usage-needs-auth-strong">
    <span class="btn__text ">Oled Telia klient?</span>
    <svg class="icon btn__icon-right ">
        <use xlink:href="/tk-telia-theme/images/icons.svg#arrow-right"></use>
    </svg>
</button>`
```