# How to call php functions from HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, raspberry-pi

I am playing around with GPIO pins on a raspberry pi and have been trying to teach myself how to get them to function via a webpage, I am familiar with python, CSS and HTML but not so much with javascript so I am struggling with this code.

I followed a tutorial on youtube where I built a basic webpage with 2 buttons that turns on and off an LED on a breadboard.

As I have the code written there, the code works fine, the LED's turn on and off.

I am trying to add more buttons to the page but I am having trouble accessing the javascript so the LED will turn on. The functioning web page is as follows.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <style>
        </style>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('#clickOn').click(function(){
                                        var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                        a.open("GET","pinOn.php");
                                        a.onreadystatechange=function(){
                                                if(a.readyState==4){
                                                        if(a.status == 200){
                                                        }
                                                        else alert("HTTP ERROR!");
                                                }
                                        }
                                        a.send();
                                });
                         $('#clickOff').click(function(){
                                        var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                        a.open("GET","pinOff.php");
                                        a.onreadystatechange=function(){
                                                if(a.readyState==4){
                                                        if(a.status == 200){
                                                        }
                                                        else alert("HTTP ERROR!");
                                                }
                                        }
                                        a.send();
                                });
                        });
                </script>
                <title>Pi GPIO Controller</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1><center>Turn the light on and off!</center></h1></br></br>
                <div class="button">
                <center><button type="button" id="clickOn">ON</center></button></br>
                <center><button type="button" id="clickOff">OFF</center></button></br>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

This is the pinOff.php file that sets pin 4 to high.

```
<?php
        system("gpio -g mode 4 out");
        system("gpio -g write 4 1");
?>
```

And the pinOn.php to set it to pin low.

```
<?php
        system("gpio -g mode 4 out");
        system("gpio -g write 4 0");
?>
```

I am trying to add another button and have tried simply adding:

```
<center><button type="button" id="clickOff">OFF</center></button></br>
```

But it isn't working.

How can I call the javascript in a button to get the code in the pinOn and pinOff files to work.

Comment: With jquery you have shortcuts for ajax-calls which are much easier to use.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax and even http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Other than that your code is correct. I tried it myself. Open devtools (f12 in chrome) and the network tab, requests are sending as they should, so recheck the serverside. simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/n8moqcy4/

Comment: [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function) You get many solutions in google.

Comment: Oh, maybe your broken html `<center><button></center></button>` should be `<center><button></button></center>`.

Comment: And those <center>-tags are from a forgotten age long long ago. Sorry, it had to be said.

Comment: Thanks ippi, that is a lot more simplified and easier to understand, I am still having the problem of only being able to reference the id once. When i add a third button to function as a second on button it doesn't work.

Comment: haha yes, once I get it to work as I want it to ill add a lot more stuff and CSS

Comment: I figured out a way to do it, i surrounded each button in a CSS class then used that in that AJAX  `$(".buttonOn").click(function() {$.get("pinOn.php");});` feel free to let me know if its a rubbish workaround.