# Input type = button fails to execute javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used this question here for reference: [Using an HTML button to call a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function)

```js
jQuery ( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {

    function demoBanner () { 

        // set click handler
        $( '#demo' ).click( function ( ) {

        alert('click registered...');
        });      
    }
    // called functions
    $ ( function () {

        demoBanner();

    });
});
```

```html
<input id="demo" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Demo Banner">

<!--jquery CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- local JS -->
<script src="http://localhost:8888/js/test.js"> </script>
```

Why isnt the function being called?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xiyihososa/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem. Either the code in the question doesn't accurately reflect the code you are testing or you got the URL to your script wrong.

Comment: There's no point in nesting a call to `$(func)` inside a call to `jQuery(document).ready(func)`. One is an alias for the other.

Comment: Here a test without problem: https://codepen.io/aureliendebord/pen/oJdYNQ Is there message in the console?

Comment: It works for me if you delete the $(function() {...} braces and call demoBanner()

Comment: It was previously working without having to remove anything. code has been copy and pasted

Comment: *it was previously working* - so what *else* changed?  Something has changed and it may not be *this* code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Also, "*it was previously working*" *"nothing changed"* - then it will still be working here (as shown by numerous comments/jsbins/codepens etc).  You need to find why it's not working and copying working code here is pointless.

Comment: Regarding comments and answers mentioning `jQuery(document).ready(` vs `$(function() { ` - these are equivalent/aliases - if you call doc ready after doc ready has been fired it, the anonymous/callback function will be run immediately, so while there's no point nesting it, it has zero impact so removing it won't *magically* make this work as it works *with* the double doc ready anyway.

Comment: @Jim if one of the posted answers is the solution you have used, it is best to mark it as the answer.

Comment: none of the posted answers helped. the solution is that i was using multiple ID's of 'demo'...unofrtunately i didnt post the surround div that had the duplicate demo.

Comment: @Jim — I'm sure there are plenty of duplicates for your real problem, you should probably just delete this question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // called functions
  demoBanner();
});
function demoBanner() {
  // set click handler
  $('#demo').click(function() {
    alert('click registered...');
  });
}
```