# How can I call a function on es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, components

I have tried so many things but it hasn't worked. I am not using react in this project so not sure how i can call the shoeAlert() function when the button is clicked. PLEASE HELP!!

```
import '../Nav/nav.styles.scss';

const Nav = () =>  {
    
    function showAlert(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I'm an alert");
    };
   return ( `
        <div class='nav'>
            <div>
                <p>Logo</p>
                <button id='btn' onclick="{this.showAlert}"> Click Me</button>
            </div>
        </div> `);
} 
 
export { Nav };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function

Comment: Is this supposed to be React? You should read up on how JSX syntax works if so.

Comment: no im not using react. Just creating components using ES6

Comment: do u know the code you write is using JSX syntax, as you says you are not using react, I am thinking if you are using Vue. Just a reminder, JSX is not understood by browser, and needs to transpile to make it work. So stay away with JSX syntax, and use normal HTML, JS to get the things done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning an HTML string, create and return the parent `.nav` element. You can attach the listener to the inner button before returning.

```
const Nav = () => {
    function showAlert(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I'm an alert");
    };
    const nav = document.createElement('div');
    nav.className = 'nav';
    nav.innerHTML = `
        <div>
            <p>Logo</p>
            <button id='btn'> Click Me</button>
        </div>
    `;
    nav.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showAlert);
    return nav;
};
```

Working snippet:

```js
const Nav = () => {
    function showAlert(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I'm an alert");
    };
    const nav = document.createElement('div');
    nav.className = 'nav';
    nav.innerHTML = `
        <div>
            <p>Logo</p>
            <button id='btn'> Click Me</button>
        </div>
    `;
    nav.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showAlert);
    return nav;
};

const nav = Nav();
document.body.appendChild(nav);
```

`showAlert` is also a standalone identifier, not a property of any instance, so you don't want `this.showAlert`, you just want `showAlert`.

Comment: Thank you!! it worked. Is there another way to do is so that i can export the Nav component in to my index.js file ?

Comment: Your existing export code will export the function just fine.

Comment: this is what i have in my index.js


import { Nav } from "../src/componentes/Nav/nav.component";


const app = () => {
    document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = Nav();
};  

app();


When i add the export in the nav after your code it returns [object HTMLDivElement] in the browser

Comment: As it says in the answer, you need to use the returned `.nav` element - don't assign the `innerHTML` of the result, use the returned element itself. Append it to whatever container you want it to be in instead.