# Html a css - button

Tags: html, css

`I need to add text when the button is clicked. But it doesnt work. I use html and css. I'm new..

This is my code...

```
 <p id="demo"></p>
<button id="btn">Klik</button>

<script>
 if(document.getElementById("btn").click())
{
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Specifically,_ what does "doesn't work" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an HTML button to call a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that document.getElementById("btn").click() doesn't check if the button is clicked; it actually simulates a click event. Here's a simple and corrected version:

```js
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Hello World";
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", changeText);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```